# AngularJs: Auto scroll enclosing div when using angular bootstrap typeahead

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a parent div within which I have bootstrap angular typeahead. When the typeahead is loaded and displayed, the parent div should auto scroll to the bottom.

I have the following html code

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="myQuestion" class="col-sm-9" style="overflow-y: auto;height: 100%;">
        <span>
            <input type="text" style="overflow:auto" ng-model="selected" 
                 typeahead="item for item in filterInput($viewValue) |   limitTo:10"
                 typeahead-on-select='onSelect($item)'>                                                                     
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The parent div should scroll to the end once the typeahead options are filtered and rendered.

I have written the directive for auto scrolling but I am not sure where to add this directive

myDirective.js

```
myApp.directive('myRepeatDirective', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, element, attr) {
                var questionInput = document.getElementById("myQuestion");
                questionInput.scrollIntoView(true);
                questionInput.focus();
            }
        }
});
```

How can I achieve auto scrolling of parent div once the type ahead loads?